# ios5: custom text field as parent's class delegate

Tags: ios, delegates

I created a custom text field class

```
@interface NumericTextField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<NumericTextFieldDelegate> numericTFDelegate;
@end
```

and I want it to be the delegate of it's parent

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.numericTFDelegate numericTextFieldDidBeginEditing:self];
}

- (void) doInit {

    self.delegate = self;
    self.numericTFDelegate = nil;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [self doInit];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self doInit];
    }
    return self;
}
```

It works fine on iOS6 and iOS7, but on iOS5 it fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 2 when I try to edit the field.

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Can post the debugger output when you receive the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, also add an `All Exceptions` breakpoint to get more information about the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: Debugger output is: Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Enable Zombies, set the `All Exceptions` breakpoint and try again, the things you post now are not enough to go on.

Comment: I did "Enable Zombie Objects" and set the "All Exceptions" breakpoint. I never used these, but I don't see any difference - no additional output, the breakpoint doesn't break anything.